# Ruby cannot get Azure VM metadata from Azure Instance Metadata service

Tags: ruby, azure, metadata

According to MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service
Azure provide instance metadata service at "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01" . 
But I failed to get the metadata on one of my VMs with ruby. While, I can get the metadata with PowerShell.
OS Environment: Windows Server 2012R2.
Ruby version: ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
PowerShell version: 4.0

PowerShell code:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"
```

response from powershell code:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
...
```

Ruby Code:

```
require 'net/http'

AZURE_METADATA_ADDR = "169.254.169.254".freeze unless defined?(AZURE_METADATA_ADDR) 
AZURE_METADATA_URL = "/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01".freeze unless defined?(AZURE_METADATA_URL)

def http_get(uri) 
conn = Net::HTTP.start(AZURE_METADATA_ADDR) 
conn.read_timeout = 6 
conn.get(uri, { "Metadata" => "true" }) 
end

puts "Fetching metadata from host #{AZURE_METADATA_ADDR} at #{AZURE_METADATA_URL}" 
response = http_get(AZURE_METADATA_URL)

puts response
```

Response from Ruby code:

```
Fetching metadata from host 169.254.169.254 at /metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01 
#<Net::HTTPNotFound:0x0000000002372128>
```

Anyone can advice how to continue troubleshooting this issue? Is the problem inside Ruby? 
PS. this is an embedded Ruby provided by chef client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an environment variable "http_proxy" is preventing ruby from accessing the endpoint. The resolution is to set "no_proxy" environment variable and set '169.254.169.254' in the list of "no_proxy".

Ruby honors "http_proxy" while other languages like powershell and java don't honor it.

Answer (score 0):

So, this worked for me:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

http = Net::HTTP.new('169.254.169.254', '80')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01')
request['Metadata'] = 'true'
response = http.request(request)
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

... on Ruby 2.5.5. The only obvious difference I see is the explicit port setting to '80'.